# Defer loading of Facebook Like Button Script

Tags: jquery, facebook, deferred-loading

Google pagespeed is complaining about my facebook like button script. How can I defer the script?

> 45KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing
>   JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.
>   http://static.ak.facebook.com/.../xd_arbiter.php?... (21KiB of inline
>   JavaScript) https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/.../xd_arbiter.php?...
>   (21KiB of inline JavaScript) http://www.facebook.com/.../like.php?...
>   (3KiB of inline JavaScript)

Here's the code I'm using and I'm loading it into a .js file in the footer of my page.

```
(function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.async=true;
        js.defer=true;//THIS DOES NOT APPEAR TO SATISFY PAGESPEED
        js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
    (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")
);
```

Results in the following script tag (via Chrome's inspector):

```
    <script 
    id="facebook-jssdk" 
    async="" 
    defer="" 
    src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Comment: [Socialite.js](http://socialitejs.com/) is a great library that makes this incredibly easy to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the setTimeout luke!

```
setTimeout( function () {
   (function(d,s,id){
         // load js
         ...
      }
      (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")
   );
}, 3000);
```

You can throw the load in another 'thread' to async or Defer it

Comment: that's amazing. 20points of google page speed insight gained with such a small tweak! thanks ghost!

Comment: I feel so wrong when set the timeout for this. Could we do it more dynamic+

Comment: If you just want the defer attribute to work use this code:
`js.async = true; js.setAttribute('defer', 'defer');`

Answer (score 4):

setTimeout works but it's not real defer, since if the page finished loading after the time set (in this case 3 seconds) the like button will be loaded before the page finished loading.

I put the like button's javscript code inside my own function and nested it inside the

```
<script>
    function FbButtonLoad(){
      (function(d,s,id){
         // load js
         ...
      }
      (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")
   );
}
</script>
```

then I set it in the body tag to run on page load:

```
<body onload="FbButtonLoad();">
```

The button appears on the page where I left it's containers:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="350" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: it's better to put `FbButtonLoad();` into `$(window).load()` instead of `onload` to separate Javascript from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly less than perfect solution (HTML5 only) would be to load the library on DOMContentLoaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    (function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
    (document, "script", "facebook-jssdk")
);
```